# React Native: Unable to download JS bundle

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

He creado la aplicación de ejemplo en React Native, siguiendo el tutorial inicial que tiene el sitio oficial:

[React Native Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-setup)

Pero, cuando ejecuto

> react-native run-android

Me encuentro con el siguiente error:

[image: Error cuando se ejecuta run-android]

Alguno que sepa si seguí mal las indicaciones o falta algo extra en esa guía inicial?

Comment: ¿Podrías pegar tu código para saber qué hiciste mal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo tuve ese mismo problema, pude resolverlo con el siguiente [comando](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html#content)

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Este comando funciona con dispositivos android versión 5.0 o superior,
adb reverse permite redireccionar un puerto del dispositivo hacia la computadora.

Comment: muy buen aporte, desconocía de este detalle, gracias!.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de correr `react-native run-android`, en otra terminal escribe `react-native start`